# Combine LINQ queries

Tags: c#, linq

I'm in the process of making a small query thing for a set of results of files.

```
public class f_results
    {
        public String name { get; set; }
        public DateTime cdate { get; set; }
        public DateTime mdate { get; set; }
        public DateTime adate { get; set; }
        public Int64 size { get; set; }
    }
```

I have a screen on which users can select what they want. At the moment I go through a filter system:

```
    foundfiles = new BindingList<f_results>(totalresults.Find(fname.Text,true));
    if (fsize.Text.Trim() != "")
    {
        try
        {
            Int64 sz = Int64.Parse(fsize.Text);
            List<f_results> y = (from p in foundfiles where p.size >= sz orderby p.size descending select p  ).ToList();
            foundfiles = new BindingList<f_results>(y);
        }
        catch
        { }
    }
    if (adate.Text.Trim() != "")
    {
        try
        {
            List<f_results> y;
            DateTime test = DateTime.Parse(adate.Text);
            if ((adateop.Text) == ">")
            {
                y = (from p in foundfiles where p.adate >= test select p).ToList();
            }
            else
                y = (from p in foundfiles where p.adate <= test select p).ToList();
            foundfiles = new BindingList<f_results>(y);
        }
        catch
        { }
    }

    if (mdate.Text.Trim() != "")
    {
        try
        {
            List<f_results> y;
            DateTime test = DateTime.Parse(mdate.Text);
            if ((mdateop.Text) == ">")
            {
                y = (from p in foundfiles where p.mdate >= test select p).ToList();
            }
            else
                y = (from p in foundfiles where p.mdate <= test select p).ToList();
            foundfiles = new BindingList<f_results>(y);
        }
        catch
        { }
    }

    if (cdate.Text.Trim() != "")
    {
        try
        {
            List<f_results> y;
            DateTime test = DateTime.Parse(cdate.Text);
            if ((cdateop.Text) == ">")
            {
                y = (from p in foundfiles where p.cdate >= test select p).ToList();
            }
            else
                y = (from p in foundfiles where p.cdate <= test select p).ToList();
            foundfiles = new BindingList<f_results>(y);
        }
        catch
        { }
    }
```

At the end, I have my results the way I want them, but I'm looking to process about 72 TB of file data so, there are plenty of files and plenty of directories in my list (totalresults is a type results, which contains a list of files (f_results) and directories (results).. Find then iterates down and returns a massive list of f_results which match a given regex.

Is there a way to make my LINQ query one query? Given not all options maybe used, e.g. they may just want files > x, or not used since.. or.. etc.

I did consider making flags for the test, and so on, as it's the test part that's the most important.. is that the better way, or is there better? Or does it not matter much in the wash?

Comment: To speedup large input processing you can use [Parallel LINQ (PLINQ)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688.aspx)?

Comment: Maybe, have you an example answer to my problem (while Im trying to poke it with sticks to see if I can do it other ways?) - btw example of sequential linq shows http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460680.aspx and it didnt really cover actual sequential linq queries in the way this problem is.

Comment: I've read question one more time, so you want be able dynamically build single LINQ query depends on filter parameters specified as a string? or what is your main objective?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could generate your filters beforehand, then apply them all at once - you would only have to iterate your initial enumeration once, something like this (shortened):

```
IEnumerable<f_results> foundfiles = new List<f_results>();
var filters = new List<Func<f_results, bool>>();

if (fsize.Text.Trim() != "")
{
    long sz = long.Parse(fsize.Text);
    filters.Add(x => x.size >= sz);
}

if (adate.Text.Trim() != "")
{
    DateTime test = DateTime.Parse(adate.Text);
    filters.Add(x => x.adate >= test);
}

foreach (var filter in filters)
{
    var filterToApply = filter;
    foundfiles = foundfiles.Where(filterToApply);
}
finalResults = new BindingList<f_results>(foundfiles);
```

More importantly don't call `ToList()` until you have processed all filters, otherwise you keep iterating through your full result list over and over.

Comment: I like the look of this! (See a comment I will add in a sec)

Comment: Thats very good. I would change the foreach loop to "foundfiles = foundfiles.Where(file => filters.All(filter => filter(file)))".

Comment: Thank you BrokenGlass, I do like your solution. I did find a way to do it as a single query - in case anyone cared, so have posted my own answer (see below), but, I am going to investigate this. I do like it.

Comment: OK have plugged this in, and the only issue I had was BindingList<f_results>(foundfiles) wouldnt accept the foundfiles type without a .ToList() on the end.. What did I miss?

Comment: That's right - `BindingList` only takes an `IList<T>` in its constructor, so you have to do that - didn't look that up at the time

Comment: I need to get my data together and work out if yours or my answer is actually faster, I do like yours, yours is easier to work with and can of course be more flexible long term.. (especially with Yorye's change)

Comment: Im glad I found 2 answers - my own - always good to find one of your own, it works, its readable, but, I love this one. Just because you can create the filters at any time, anywhere, and then apply them.  Now all I need to fix is the fact its running out of memory when working through all the files (having 3 dates in there apparently is too much for it, its dying around the 510k directory mark)

Comment: @BugFinder: Try using `Directory.EnumerateFiles` instead of `GetFiles` so you don't have to load everything into memory (if that's how you are getting your files currently)

Comment: Oh, other interesting side effect - I found a 2k864bit to run it on.. So spec of 32bit server is a 2CPU4GB box(works out 4CPU in task manger), the 64bit is a monster, has 24CPU in task manager and 60GB memory.. So, why is my 32bit one processing 300 directories a sec on average the 64bit one about 20!!!

Comment: Most likely your code is IO bound - I would assume the 32 bit machine has a much better disk and/or a RAID - doesn't fully explain the factor of 10 though

Comment: I havent the tools (only got c# express as it is) to do much more with it (grr) both boxes should have raid. considering the 32bit one is 7 years old I really thought the bottle neck would be sucking details off the network, oh well.. least the 32bit is mine to butcher to my own likeing :)

Comment: Darn - it got to about 540k directories and died :( grrr

Comment: Going to have to investigate memory mapped files I think

Answer (score 1):

At least I suggest to remove the `.ToList()` invokes everywhere. As LINQ has a deferred invocation, it will iterate once, even you have:

```
var foundfiles = from p in foundfiles where p.size >= sz select p ;
foundfiles = from p in foundfiles where p.mdate >= test select p
```

**Update** (in that case order by should be put after all filters)

But if you write:

```
var foundfiles = (from p in foundfiles where p.size >= sz orderby p.size descending select p).ToList() ;
foundfiles = (from p in foundfiles where p.mdate >= test select p).ToList();
```

It will iterate two times - and that might be a serious performance problem.

But I don't think the code will look much simpler if you make this code as a single query.

Also, why are you catching all exceptions? You shouldn't do that.

Comment: The reason the tolist was there originally was because it may not do other tests. The catch all was because its work in progress and right now, if it screws up I want it to continue on and try the rest :) Tidy will come later.

Comment: You could have had only one ToList() in the end :)

Answer (score 1):

OK - I wanted to semi answer my own question..

I can combine to a single query, the following works very well.. Ideal? Possibly not!

Am going to now look at BrokenGlass' suggestion which looks nice and tidy!

```
   Boolean flag_size = false;
    Boolean flag_adate = false;
    Boolean flag_cdate = false;
    Boolean flag_mdate = false;
    Int64 sz=0;
    DateTime adatetest=DateTime.Now;
    DateTime cdatetest = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime mdatetest = DateTime.Now;
    String mop = mdateop.Text;
    String aop = adateop.Text;
    String cop = cdateop.Text;

    if (fsize.Text.Trim() != "")
    {
        try
        {
            sz = Int64.Parse(fsize.Text);
            flag_size = true;
        }
        catch { }
    }

    if (adate.Text.Trim() != "")
    {
        try
        {
            adatetest = DateTime.Parse(adate.Text);
            flag_adate = true;
        }
        catch
        { }
    }
    if (cdate.Text.Trim() != "")
    {
        try
        {
            cdatetest = DateTime.Parse(cdate.Text);
            flag_cdate = true;
        }
        catch
        { }
    }
    if (mdate.Text.Trim() != "")
    {
        try
        {
            mdatetest = DateTime.Parse(mdate.Text);
            flag_mdate = true;
        }
        catch
        { }
    }


    foundfiles = new BindingList<f_results>(totalresults.Find(fname.Text, true));


            List<f_results> y = (from p in foundfiles.AsParallel() 
                                 where  (!flag_size || (flag_size && p.size >= sz)) &&
                                        (!flag_mdate || (flag_mdate && mop == ">" && p.mdate >= mdatetest) || (flag_mdate && mop == "< " && p.mdate >= mdatetest)) &&
                                        (!flag_adate || (flag_adate && aop == ">" && p.adate >= adatetest) || (flag_adate && aop == "< " && p.adate >= adatetest)) &&
                                        (!flag_cdate || (flag_cdate && cop == ">" && p.cdate >= cdatetest) || (flag_cdate && cop == "< " && p.cdate >= cdatetest))
                                 orderby p.size descending 
                                 select p).ToList();

            foundfiles = new BindingList<f_results>(y);
```