# Using memory mapped file to compensate for out of memory in C#

Tags: c#, out-of-memory

I have a problem - previously I was after an algorithm to solve a part of it (see *[Combine LINQ queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804683/combine-linq-queries/9804942#9804942)*) anyway, and I have come to a huge issue.

At around 540k directories, it's crashing out with out of memory. :(

I am trying to process and store the company SAN file information, and we need to do this, because we have people who keep data for 25 years and they don't need to, but it's hard to track. It's a total of up to 70 TB of files. So, as you can imagine, it's a lot of files.

From what I've read however, memory mapped files can't be dynamic? Is this true? I can't know prior how many files + directories there are for sure.

If not, (please say not), can someone do me a short example on how to make a dynamic mapped file (code provided in the *[Combine LINQ queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804683/combine-linq-queries/9804942#9804942)* question). In short, I create a directory structure in memory holding directory → directories + files(name, size, access date, modified date, and creation date).

Any clues would be appreciated as this would get around my problem if it's possible.

Comment: Have you considered using a database instead of an in-memory representation?

Comment: Yes, I had, but the queries I wanted to run would become very hiddious, such as reading through and summing up the size of a directory and its subparts.. etc.

Comment: Still, it's probably your best bet. Make that surely. Solving this type of problem is what database are for.

Comment: except the data life time is short. We need to be able to run this every couple of hours and scrap what we had to start with and get results quickly - a memory mapping would solve the problem in a short term basis - this app may never be used again as we are getting them to have a clear out

Comment: Do you need to have *everything* in memory at the same time? Can't you process sub-directories, sum up their content, and throw them away (ie. memory-wise)?

Comment: Thats what Im trying now, as initially I read the top directories and had been doing a parallel process of them - was getting through 200+ directories a second, but, the problem is, we may need to ask it "show files which havent been accessed in 5 years" or "files bigger than 2gb" so hence a memory mapped file would be useful as the code is there works, just not quite on this scale - as obviously its a lot of files.

Comment: Not to sound too simple, but what OS do you have? If you're on 64bit, it would cost you 1 hour and some $100 to add 16 GB if memory. That might do the trick.

Comment: What exactly are you going to store in this memory-mapped file?  You realise you will need to implement your own index within it, to locate objects to their correct offset etc.  You would be *writing your own database* - so just use one that's already provided.

Comment: OK as discussed on the linq post, when I ran it on 64bit (after a recompile to make it 64 bit) I ran same exe on a 32bit 4cpu 3gb box, got 300 directories a second. Ran it on a 64bit 24 cpu and 60gb box.. got 20 directories a second.. latter of course then is.. too slow! OK, so we have established a memory mapped file isnt what I hoped - in Delphi you could semi do it invisibly, so it thought it was memory.. Darn it.

Comment: Are you using FileSystemWatcher for tracking changes? If not, I would suggest to move from periodical rescan to event based incremental updates, in such case you'll be able to run on 64bit and have more memory on hand. Also, that performance drop from 32bit to 64bit looks suspicious to me, either hdd io is drastically different, either something is wrong in code, such move should not cost 15x performance.

Comment: Totally agree Giedrius, I didnt expect anything like the performance drop - although I believe (without checking) the 64bit was a virtual. Unless I can store the initial scan, filesystemwatcher wont help.

Comment: As an update - by dumping each top level directory out as it finishes the walk down, I generated 490mb of data for 1 area (3 areas, this is probably the smallest) in 63 minutes. While 63 minutes is arguably too long.. If I can use something like gjvdkamp's idea, and write to disk and serialise it so use it from disk as he showed, as once written I can do the queries after, thats fine. All I need now is to work out how to serialise nested items!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you can't fit the whole thing into memory you can stream your data with an IEnumerable Below's an example of that. I've been playing around with MemoryMapped files as well since I need the last drop of perf, but so far I've stuck with BinaryReader/Writer.

For the DB advocates: When you really need the last drop of perf, I do my own binary files as well. Going out of process to a DB really adds overhead. Also the whole security/ logging, ACID etc does add up.

Here's an example that streams your f_results class.

**EDIT**

Updated example to show how to write/read a tree of directory info. I keep 1 file that holds all the directories. This tree is loaded into memory in one go, and then points to the files where all the f_results are. 
You still have to create a seperate file per directory that holds the f_results for all the files. How to do that depends on your code, but you should be able to figure that out.

Good luck!

```
public class f_results {
    public String name { get; set; }
    public DateTime cdate { get; set; }
    public DateTime mdate { get; set; }
    public DateTime adate { get; set; }
    public Int64 size { get; set; }

    // write one to a file
    public void WriteTo(BinaryWriter wrtr) {
        wrtr.Write(name);
        wrtr.Write(cdate.Ticks);
        wrtr.Write(mdate.Ticks);
        wrtr.Write(adate.Ticks);
        wrtr.Write(size);
    }

    // read one from a file
    public f_results(BinaryReader rdr) {
        name = rdr.ReadString();
        cdate = new DateTime(rdr.ReadInt64());
        mdate = new DateTime(rdr.ReadInt64());
        adate = new DateTime(rdr.ReadInt64());
        size = rdr.ReadInt64();
    }

    // stream a whole file as an IEnumerable (so very little memory needed)
    public static IEnumerable<f_results> FromFile(string dataFilePath) {
        var file = new FileStream(dataFilePath, FileMode.Open);
        var rdr = new BinaryReader(file);
        var eos = rdr.BaseStream.Length;
        while (rdr.BaseStream.Position < eos) yield return new f_results(rdr);
        rdr.Close();
        file.Close();
    }
}

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {

        var d1 = new DirTree(@"C:\",
            new DirTree(@"C:\Dir1",
                new DirTree(@"C:\Dir1\Dir2"),
                new DirTree(@"C:\Dir1\Dir3")
                ),
                new DirTree(@"C:\Dir4",
                new DirTree(@"C:\Dir4\Dir5"),
                new DirTree(@"C:\Dir4\Dir6")
                ));

        var path = @"D:\Dirs.dir";

        // write the directory tree to a file
        var file = new FileStream(path, FileMode.CreateNew | FileMode.Truncate);
        var w = new BinaryWriter(file);
        d1.WriteTo(w);
        w.Close();
        file.Close();

        // read it from the file
        var file2 = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
        var rdr = new BinaryReader(file2);
        var d2 = new DirTree(rdr);

        // now inspect d2 in debugger to see that it was read back into memory

        // find files bigger than (roughly) 1GB
        var BigFiles = from f in f_results.FromFile(@"C:\SomeFile.dat")
                       where f.size > 1e9
                       select f;
    }
}

class DirTree {
    public string Path { get; private set; }
    private string FilesFile { get { return Path.Replace(':', '_').Replace('\\', '_') + ".dat"; } }

    public IEnumerable<f_results> Files() {
        return f_results.FromFile(this.FilesFile);
    }

    // you'll want to encapsulate this in real code but I didn't for brevity
    public DirTree[] _SubDirectories;

    public DirTree(BinaryReader rdr) {
        Path = rdr.ReadString();
        int count = rdr.ReadInt32();
        _SubDirectories = new DirTree[count];
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) _SubDirectories[i] = new DirTree(rdr);
    }

    public DirTree( string Path, params DirTree[] subDirs){
        this.Path = Path;
        _SubDirectories = subDirs;
    }

    public void WriteTo(BinaryWriter w) {
        w.Write(Path);           
        w.Write(_SubDirectories.Length);
        // depth first is the easiest way to do this
        foreach (var f in _SubDirectories) f.WriteTo(w);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I would first look into using a RAM disk before starting with memory mapped files.

Comment: I have an SSD. I'm on a custom windows build that only comes in 32Bit for now (Bank), so that would eat up too much memeory I'm afraid.

Comment: This looks promising, it would lose my directory structure, but this has most certainly given me an idea! Thank you!

Comment: Yeah this is a simple example on how to do this. Serializing nested classes is not much harder. There's also a more inbetween solution in protobuf-net you might want to investigate. It can handle the boilerplate stuff can be more robust.

Comment: OK, have you a simple example of a nested one? I write out each top dir of 1 area and came to 175 chunks totalling 490mb - which isnt so bad, but thats the smaller of the 3 areas Im looking at - it took 63 minute, so I can read it in and convert it out to something else if necessary.

Comment: Guess I would put the files from Directory c:/x/y/z in a file called c_x_y_z.dat. Then you can call f_result.FromFile(this.CleanPath()) from the directory class. Don;t have time right now to write the code for nesting everything nto one file sorry. The simple idea is that when you write all the f_results in a directory to the file, you first wirte the numebr of f_results, and then write them. When reading, you first read how many you;re going to read, then read then in a loop. So instead of checking for eos, you just loop: for(i=0;i<result_count;i++)yield return f_result(rdr).

Comment: I dont mind the multi file path thing, except next biggest chunk of disk space clocks in at 1M+ directories... right now I have successfully read them into their top directory chunks, eg a results (containing more results and f_results) its over a 1GBs worth of data, however, if someone can point me at an example recursive class version of this code Im thinking you have the answer, I just need a litle more picture to convert it into my work.

Comment: updated the example to have a seperate directory tree that you load in one go. THen you can iterate over all the files lazily. Reading the directory tree in a lazy fashion should also be possible but is a little more involved. Although I'm starting to see that if your files change a lot, it will be rather cumbersome to keep all this info up to date.... I usually create a file with snapshot of the portfolio and then crunch that a lot of times. Not sure of this file appraoch will actually be the sweet spot for your problem..

Comment: It shouldnt change "a lot" what we are after doing is most likely a run before the clean up, a run near the end of the clean up, and a run after.. I have asked if theres any pre-set questions they want answers for, eg, if they want to look for *.mp3 or *.pst or files > 1gb or files in a directory totalling more than say 1gb.. any preset questions would be easier than grabbing all and asking later.

Comment: ok then this should work for you and be as fast as it can be.

Comment: Thanks for the updated example. Im gonna see if I can give this a go :)