# LINQ. Want to add where clause dynamically. I'm afraid of IOs to DB

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-web-api

I use ASP.NET Web API and Repository pattern.
And I want to add where clause dynamically. Like,

```
//controller
  static readonly ICustomerRepository repository = new CustomerRepository();
  //
 var result = repository.GetAll();

 if (form['name'] != null) result.Where( p => p.custName.Contains( form['name'].toString() ) );
 if (form['attribute1'] != null) result.Where( p => p.attribute1.Equals( form['attribute1'].toString() ) );
 return result;
//
```

Isn't there any afraid of IOs?

Comment: "Isn't there any afraid of IOs?" - Can you please translate this sentence? It's entirely unclear what it means.

Comment: more details / more specification. in order to prevent misinterpretation, don't use shortcuts.

Comment: IOs is, I mean database access, SQL query to Database. I'm afraid to execute SQL several times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Isn't there any afraid of IOs?

It's not really clear what you mean, but the query will only be sent to the database when you try to execute it - which is presumably in some of the code which calls your method. It's not like it's going to execute once for `GetAll`, then once for the first `Where` clause, then once for the second `Where` clause. It will all be packaged into a single query, when you start fetching the data from the `IQueryable<>`.

Comment: Thank you. " the query will only be sent to the database when you try to execute it " I just want to know that.

Comment: Jon, you really handled IOs well here ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want multiple where clauses, take a look at this question I asked: [Combine LinQ queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804683/combine-linq-queries)

I had a similar problem. I wanted to take a query screen and then apply the results accordingly, the answer I got was perfect for what I needed

Comment: Thank you. I read the link. Is there any difference to add where clause directly(my pattern) and to add where clause using filter( the link Answer)?

Comment: Yes, you get all records, then you strip some, then strip more, you will do more processing.. whereas if you tell it do it in one hit, its more like "get the stuff I wanted"

Comment: I think, the way of the link's Answer is the same to "strip some" several times in the foreach loop line   "foundfiles.Where(filterToApply)". Is anything wrong if my idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you access `data-base`, there is almost always `IO` access, if there is not some memory caching setup. So it depends how do you manage `data-base`. But in general, `data-base` is tuned to have high performance `IO` access, so untill you're not going to write large scale application,I personally, would not warry mush about `IO` operations overhead on simple queries like this.

If you would like to *optimize* query, by making it (say) one single query, you can find a relation between these 2 datas and make [InnerJoin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397941.aspx) on them.

Comment: hm, could it be possible that IO means 'InvalidOperation' in this case?

Comment: **To me** it seems OP's talking about IO storage acess.

Comment: Sorry, my question is unclear.I want to know when sql query execute.

Answer (score 0):

The query will be executed when you actually get the data, so you can stack conditions to it without causing it to fetch all the records from the database.

However, you have to assign the result to something, or you will just be creating expressions and throwing them away:

```
var result = repository.GetAll();

if (form['name'] != null) {
  result = result.Where( p => p.custName.Contains( form['name'].toString() ) );
}
if (form['attribute1'] != null) {
  result = result.Where( p => p.attribute1.Equals( form['attribute1'].toString() ) );
}
return result; // or return result.ToList();
```

Consider if you want to run the actual query at the end of the method by adding `ToList`, or if you want to return the expression to be executed by the code calling the method.

Comment: Thank you. I have a better understanding of LINQ.