# Advanced filtering in linq

Tags: c#, linq

I'm here to ask a question on how would a code look like when it came to advanced filtering in C# with LINQ. I have experience with Linq, but this is something that was out of my understanding.

Lets say we have a class `Item` that has properties `(string)Name`, `(bool)New` and `(int)Price` and users would have to input their filters and get the results they need.

Lets say we put 5 objects inside a list `list` that is a List of Items.

```
new Item("Pen",true,12);
new Item("PostIt",false,35);
new Item("Phone",true,140);
new Item("Watch",true,5);
new Item("Lavalamp",false,2);
```

Now I woud like to process this information to get.. All New times that cost over 10. I know I can do this with

```
List<Item> Results = list.where(item => item.Price> 10 && item.New).ToList();
```

but what if a user wants to get all items that cost over 10 regardless of being new or not.. I can't change the query during runtime to fit the needs and I don't think that making a query for every possible combination of input parameters is a right way to do this... Can someone give me an example on how this should be done?

Comment: Maybe this? [CS-Script Source](https://csscriptsource.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Choosing%20Compiler%20Engine)

Comment: LINQ is composable. You can conditionally apply other filters however you want one at a time - no need to specify them all in a single `Where`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combine LinQ queries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804683/combine-linq-queries)  this was a query I put in on combining queries but you can build up a big list of things depending on various criteria, and then run them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define base query

```
var result = list.Where(item=> item.Price > 10); //DON'T Call ToList() here

if(someCondition)
    result = result.Where(item=> item.New);

//in the end you are calling

return result.ToList();
```

Like @MikeEason said you don't want to call `ToList()` on your first result because this will execute the query. Your goal is to build the complex query and execute it only once. Because of that this is done when you return the result.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this method effectively *builds up* the query and it is only executed when it hits `.ToList()`.

Comment: @MikeEason Yes I was going to write this.

Comment: The ToList() wasn't really an important part of the question, but thanks for noticing it and writing the answer around it. Reason why I'm asking for this is a project that might even take up to 50,60 optional filters. Thanks for the  answer, it did answer my question!

Answer (score 3):

If you only have those three conditions then you can build your query in several steps:

```
IEnumerable<Item> result=list;
int Price=10;
bool FilterByPrice, bool FilterByNew;//Set this variables in your environment
if(FilterByPrice)
  result=result.Where(item => item.Price> Price);
if(FilterByNew)
  result=result.Where(item => item.New);
```

Your query will be executed when you call `ToList` method or went you iterate over the query result thanks to [deferred execution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738633(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: At first I thought there would be a simpler method, but if this is the case, damn, it's going to be a lot of ifs there. Thank you! I'll upvote your answer but I'll chose mybirthname's answer as The answer since it has more upvotes and code looks a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

So let's say your items exist in your database and you want to query them. The user has a checkbox, if he wants to see only new items or all of them. If the box is checked you set a bool value for it.

```
// Compose the query
var results = _db.Where(item => item.Price > 10 );

// Still composing
if (onlyNewItems)
{
    results = results.Where(item => item.New);
}

// ToList() executes the query, data is returned;
return results.ToList();
```

This does not run the query twice. In fact, until you materialize your query, you are still composing it. If you would return it now, it would be of type `IQueryable<T>`. Only after you call `.ToList()`, is your query actually executed and you get an `IEnumerable<T>` in this case a `List<T>` back.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation, I did not know that. I thought all linq queries are considered as a query.

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<Item> Results = list.where(item => item.Price > 10 
                                      && (condition ? item.New : true)).ToList();
```

you can extend this way. just pass `true` if your condition is false and it is like nothing is happened.